# CoreBluetooth command line macOS

Tags: objective-c, command-line

I would like to build a Simulink Coder block which communicates to BLE device on macOS. Therefore, it is needed to wrap the objective C code framework of CoreBluetooth into a C++ wrapper. I wanted to start with a command line application in Xcode but all examples use only the View for accessing CBCentralDelegate etc. Is there somewhere a good example of a commandline objective C CoreBluetooth Central implementation.

Thanks,